# Improve reading speed of MySQL table storing stock prices (100 Mil. entries)

Tags: mysql, select, query-performance

I have a table which stores stock prices in a MySQL database with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_prices` (
  `price_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stock_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datasource_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `price_time_frame` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `price_open` double NOT NULL,
  `price_close` double NOT NULL,
  `price_low` double NOT NULL,
  `price_high` double NOT NULL,
  `price_volume` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`price_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_entry` (`stock_id`,`datasource_id`,`price_time`,`price_time_frame`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

The table mainly acts as a storage, meaning that all data for each stock and time frame is loaded into memory on application start. New stock prices are continuously written to the database.

A common query for loading all prices for a given stock looks like this:

```
SELECT price_open, price_high, price_low, price_close, price_volume, price_time 
FROM tbl_prices
WHERE stock_id=1 AND datasource_id=2 AND price_time_frame=864000
ORDER BY price_time;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT price_open, price_high, price_low, price_close, price_volume, price_time 
FROM tbl_prices
WHERE stock_id=1 AND datasource_id=2 AND price_time_frame=864000
ORDER BY price_time;
```

results in:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  tbl_prices  range   unique_entry    unique_entry    24  NULL    113036  Using index condition
```

The table contains more than 100 million entries.

Everything works fine but loading of the prices from the table uses a considerable amount of time. How could I speed up the table architecture?

Regards,

Comment: Why don't you look at indexing as well?

Comment: There are some unanswered questions. How many rows are typically matched by a query like you showed? Is the unique key index being used effectively, as shown in an EXPLAIN of your query? Is your server hardware sufficient to host that much data? What's the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and how does that compare to the total size of the table and its index?

Comment: I added the ``EXPLAIN`` statement. The pool size is ``1024M``. The machine uses only a fraction of its resources during processing (less than 20% CPU of 4/8 cores, 1.2GB RAM out of 24GB, less than 100MB/s writing speed of a fast SSD).

Comment: how long is `a considerable amount of time`? 10 seconds or 10 hours? and what do you think is acceptable ?

Comment: In your EXPLAIN I see it's using a `range` access, when you should use `ref` because you are doing all equality comparisons. I agree with @GMB's answer, you should change the order of columns in your index.

Comment: I also can make a rough guess that your table + index occupies about 13-14 GB (I filled an InnoDB table like the one you show with 1 million rows, then multiplied by 100x). Using a 1GB buffer pool seems too small. I recommend increasing that if you can, since you have 24GB of RAM on the server. But don't overallocate if you have other apps or processes that need to use that RAM.

Comment: Could there be a benefit in partitioning the table where each partition contains all rows for the index "`stock_id`,`datasource_id`,`price_time_frame`"? How could such an partition be created?

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer the whole question but as a first hint, I would suggest changing the order of the columns in the definition of the unique key, from:

```
`unique_entry` (`stock_id`, `datasource_id`, `price_time`, `price_time_frame`)
```

To:

```
`unique_entry` (`stock_id`, `datasource_id`, `price_time_frame`, `price_time`)
```

This puts first all the column that come into play in the `where` predicates, and *then* the ordering column, so this gives the database a better chance to take full advantage of the index.

Also: do you *really* need `select *`? The more columns you get, the bigger the payload the database has to process (and return). You should enumerate the columns that you really want. Ideally, you would only extract columns that belong to the index: this makes the index *covering* for the query, and the database might be ble to execute the whole query by looking at the index only.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I changed the order of the column names and there is indeed a marginal performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

as sysadmin I would suggest:

- Use index for `stock_id`,`datasource_id`,`price_time_frame` (where or order by column)
- Use Solid-state drives over HDDs ( a single 7200 RPM drive is limited to 200 I/O and an enterprise SSD disk is 50,000 I/O)
- Edit Mysql Server Settings like:`innodb_buffer_pool_size`,`innodb_io_capacity`
  this combination between table schema , server settings and hardware will give you very good preformence

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `price_id` for anything?  If not, get rid of it and promote the `UNIQUE KEY` to be `PRIMARY KEY`.

InnoDB "clusters" the PK with the data.  Hence, when you fetch rows based on the PK (as GMB suggested), the rest of the data will be right there.  That is, there is no need to reach over into another BTree to get the other columns.

This might more than double the speed (for your case).